# Необходимо ли двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Благодаря им мы узнали как жили люди их времени, их заботы. Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания и нужно ли двоеточие после слова «узнали»?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Это сложное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным, перед союзным словом КАК ставится запятая. Кроме того, желательно изменить грамматику предложения, введя в его состав еще одно придаточное вместо дополнения "их заботы".

Благодаря им мы узнали,  как жили люди их времени, какие у них были  заботы.

Answer (score 0):

После "узнали" знак, конечно, нужен. Но вряд ли это двоеточие. При такой пунктуации вы претендуете на то, что дальше идет список членов, которые однородных общему слову "узнали". Не думаю, что здесь это выглядит естественным.

Грамматика здесь по смыслу другая. Это СПП, которое нужно отделить запятой. И при этом вторая часть ("их заботы"), лишенная союзного слова, оказывается, как верно заметил Sergey, оторванной от "узнали". В принципе такое возможно, грамматика позволяет, но все-таки лучше, как отмечает Sergey, какой-то союз или союзное слово использовать в избежание недоразумений.